# Deploy ASP.NET Core App using Docker via SSH

Tags: docker, ssh, asp.net-core, docker-compose

I successfully created 2 Docker containers like described [here](https://www.sep.com/sep-blog/2017/02/27/nginx-reverse-proxy-to-asp-net-core-separate-docker-containers/) - the first one is for my asp.net core website and the second one is for nginx. How can I deploy it to my VPS using SSH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it working:

1) Build images locally: `docker-compose build`. You will get 2 images (`website` and `nginx`)

2) Save these images: `docker save website_image nginx_image > images.tar` (image names can differ depends on your yml file)

3) Copy archive to vps: `rsync images.tar user@host:/home/myfolder`

4) Create new `docker-compose.yml` from existing. All you need is to replace 
`build:` sections with `image: image_name`

5) Copy ths file: `rsync docker-compose.yml user@host:/home/myfolder`

6) SSH to dir with `images.tar` file and load images: `docker load -i images.tar`

7) Go to dir with docker compose file and start docker: `docker-compose up`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should build and push the images to a registry like https://hub.docker.com/ (or [deploy one by yourself](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/%20) ).
Then pull and run them in the target machine via ssh.